# check session not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

When loading the page I need to check the session. The page load only when there is session.

I add a code in js and called from body onload of that page, this is working fine with FF but not in IE.

my code in Js

```
checkSession= function(){
    var sessionVal = false;
    $.ajax( {
        url : 'checksession.html',
        async : false,
        success : function(data) {
            if (data.trim() == 'true') {
                sessionVal = true;
            }
        }

    });
    return sessionVal;
};
function redirectLogin(){
    if (!checkSession()) {
        jAlert("Oops... Your session has expired, please re-login...");
        window.location = cdContextPath + '/login.html';
    }   
}
```

in jsp

```
<body onload="redirectLogin();">
```

any solution ?

Comment: "it's not working" is not a sufficient description of the problem you're facing. What *happens*?

Comment: Any errors reported in Internet Explorer? Also, if you `alert()` the `data.trim()` variable, what does it look like?

Comment: Why don't you do `if (!data.trim() != 'true') { redirectLogin(); }` and run `checkSession` on page load?

Comment: If there is no session the page should not load. But using IE the page loading even if there is no session. I am using above code.

Comment: Have you checked the error console in IE?

Comment: @ Chris Kempen variable showing data.trim() variable is true or false

Comment: @Jared Farrish  there is no error

Comment: Just wondering... Why aren't you using the server-side code to do the redirect if a valid session is not part of the request? Why are you doing it on the client?

Comment: @Kandhi - I added a demonstration (with working link) of the approach I outlined.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest doing it differently.

```
var checkSession = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'checksession.html',
        dataType : 'json',
        async : false,
        success : function(data) {
            if (data.validSession != true) {
                redirectLogin();
            }
        }
    });
}

function redirectLogin(){
    jAlert("Oops... Your session has expired, please re-login...");
    window.location = cdContextPath + '/login.html';
}

$(document).ready(checkSession);
```

And then send an response back in JSON (note, this is just a mockup/example):

```
<?php

function checkSession() {
    if (yourSessionCheckStuff) {
        return 'true';
    }

    return 'false';
}

echo '{"validSession" : ' + checkSession() + '}';

// Same as the echo above, but uses json_encode()
// You only need one or the other, and I'd used
// the below.

$json = new stdClass();
$json->validSession = checkSession();

echo json_encode($json);

?>
```

**EDIT**

I created a working test case. See:

http://jfcoder.com/test/index.php

And click the links to toggle. This works without issue in IE9.

This is the code that makes it work. Note, the `$_GET` and session check are just stand-ins to demonstrate the redirect. I also replaced the `jAlert()` with a regular `alert()`.

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

if ($_GET['emulateloggedin'] == 'true') {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
} else {
    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = false;
}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Redirect Test</title>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var checkSession = function(){
    $.ajax({
        url : 'checkSession.php',
        dataType : 'json',
        async : false,
        success : function(data) {
            // Unless the returned value is true, redirect.
            if (data.validSession != 'true') {
                redirectLogin();
            }

            // You may also want to initialize any of the page
            // routines here, after the check is finished.

            // Just a suggestion, you could return the amount
            // of time the session has left and save that
            // locally. Then you could add a "You will be
            // logged out unless..." message that prompts
            // the user to continue the session or logout,
            // and automatically redirect when the time
            // runs out.
        }
    });
}

function redirectLogin(){
    alert("Oops... Your session has expired, please re-login...");
    window.location = 'login.html';
}

$(document).ready(checkSession);
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<p>If you see this, you are "logged in". <a href="index.php?emulateloggedin=false">Logout?</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**login.html**

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Login Redirect Test</title>
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
</script> 
</head>
<body>
<p>If you see this, you are "logged out". <a href="index.php?emulateloggedin=true">Login?</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

**checkSession.php**

```
<?php

session_start();

function checkSession() {
    if ($_SESSION['loggedin'] == true) {
        return 'true';
    }

    return 'false';
}

$json = new stdClass();
$json->validSession = checkSession();

echo json_encode($json);

?>
```